# system() function under cygwin

Tags: cygwin, eclipse-cdt

I develop a console program(C++) that use Cygwin and eclipse cdt. In application I have used system() function. But when I build to executable file and copy file cygwin.dll into running directory, the program can't execute system() function. 
How do I resolve this problem?
Many thanks.

Comment: What do you mean it "can't execute" the `system()` function? What happens when you try?

Comment: Thanks @KeithThompson for your reply. I have some functions such as system("pause") or system("svn diff") etc. But these functions can't execute. The application only run right when Cygwin is installed.

Comment: You didn't answer my question. *What happens*?

Comment: the system("pause"), system("svn diff").. functions are not working.

Comment: How are they "not working"? We need to know what happened, not what didn't happen. Is there an error message? How do you know it's not working?

Comment: when I using system("svn diff > test.diff") function to get diff from my repository. If I run the app on a PC which have installed Cygwin then I get diff file. Otherwise I can't get what I wish if I run the app in a PC which haven't installed Cygwin.

Comment: "... can't get what I wish" -- You're *still* telling me what *didn't* happen. Is there an error message?

Comment: no error. simply when I using system("pause") function then the app is not paused. When I using system("svn diff > test.diff") then the test.diff file is not appeared.(if running on a pc which haven't installed Cygwin).

Comment: `system()` returns an `int` result. What value does it return? Please update your question to show us in more detail just what you're doing. Someone reading your question should be able to reproduce the problem. In particular, show the *complete* source of your program and explain just what you're doing with `cygwin1.dll` (I presume that's the file you're referring to; there is no `cygwin.dll` as far as I know.) Isn't the `svn` command installed by Cygwin? If so, how do you expect it to work on a system where Cygwin isn't installed? (It's a separate command, not part of the DLL.)

Comment: "Isn't the svn command installed by Cygwin?...It's a separate command, not part of the DLL". I may understand the problem. I created a test code(include statement: cout<<system("pause");) then build it to 2 versions using Mingw and Cygwin. The system("pause") command  is working on MingW version but Cygwin version is not. So 
I understand that the "pause" and "svn" command aren't installed by Cygwin. Many thanks to @KeithThompson.